# using python to unpack selected files from 7zip archives using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, 7zip

I am currently using subprocess to unpack a selection or zip files using 7zip. I have to use this unpacking method instead of the zipfile module because on occasion the zipfile corrupts shapefiles. My current method is:

```
try:

    for file in os.listdir(downloads):
        print file
        expression2 = sevenzip + " e " +downloads + '\\' + file + " -oC:\Users\Oulton"
        print expression2

    #os.system(r"C:\Users\Oulton\7z e C:\Users\Oulton\install.zip -oC:\Users\Oulton")
        subprocess.call(expression2)



except:
        time.sleep(3)
        traceback.print_exc()
```

But this is not convenient because:

1. I only want to unpack certain .shp files and not all of the other junk in each zip
2. A shell is opened and closed for each iteration, I would prefer the shell to stay open throughout
3. I have to use manual input to overwrite duplicately named files using this method

Comment: "On occasion the zipfile [module] corrupts shapefiles"?  Is this really the case?  It seems that `zipfile` is exactly what you want -- I'd recheck this conclusion.  Or see if there's a bugfix available if it really is an issue in Python.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  If so, are you reading/writing files in binary mode? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082454/zipfile-python-module-bytesize-difference) question might be relevant.

Comment: @Managu thanks for the tip however yes even when writing binary certain shapefiles have become corrupted strangely - I repeated the process several times and it was always the same shapefiles being corrupted, which are unpacked without incident using cmd 7z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `7z e C:\Users\Oulton\install.zip -oC:\Users\Oulton" *.shp -r`
2. Use Windows's for loops to reuse the same shell: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php

3.

```
-ao (Overwrite mode) switch
Specifies the overwrite mode during extraction, to overwrite files already present on disk.
```

`-i` and `-x` can be used to respectively include or exclude specific files for extraction.

```
7z e C:\Users\Oulton\install.zip -oC:\Users\Oulton -ir!*.shp -ir!*.mxd -ir!*.shx -ir!*.sbn -ir!*.dbf -ir!*.xml
```

Comment: thanks that helps, ask for extracting just certain specific files from each zip can you give any insight?

Comment: do you know file names and directory structure?

Comment: yes I only want to extract files ending in [.shp .mxd .shx .sbn .dbf .xml]